# Sending screen shot images through sockets, need quicker idea with jpeg compression

Tags: python, sockets, compression, screenshot

Recently I made a server - client program which the client sends it's screen shot to the server through sockets. The problem is that it is very slow, about 2 frames per second.

I take every screenshot with `ImageGrab.grab()`, make it `.tostring()` and send it.

My question: Is there any way to compress the screenshot without saving it? Just compress it on the program to save time and send it. And by the way, any ideas to make it faster will be welcomed!

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help, but have you checked out the Zlib Compression library built into python? https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html

Comment: Maybe calculating the image deltas each time instead of the whole image?

Comment: This is a great idea Maltysen, I have no idea how to make it work..